# how can i customize the navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

how can i customize the navigation bar or add the background image in it and buttons of navigation bar?
please tell me in simple way not make the answer hard to understand i am not expert and?
explain step by step.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Add the code in .m file above @implementation

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {


/  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigation_bar.png"];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigationbarnew2.png"];
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 44)];


}


@end
```

### And to add button to navigation bar add the following code in viewdidload

```
UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mail-48_24.png"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image3.size.width, image3.size.height);
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendmail)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=mailbutton;
[someButton release];
```

Comment: You should never use a category to override a method. At runtime it is undefined as to which version of the method will be used.

Comment: FIRST CODE SET THE IMAGE IN BACK GROUND OF NAVIGATION BAR NOW I NEED TO SET THE IMAGE IN BACKGROUND OF NAVIGATION BAR BUTTON?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for sadly isn't that easy to accomllish. The technique required rather reminds of a workaround than a working solution It's called method swizzling and here is a tutorial on how to apply it on a navbar in order to get a custom background image in there: http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/12/21/adding-background-image-uinavigationbar/

Adding buttons to your navigationbar is fairly easy. Say your navigation bar is instansiated as navigationController:

```
UIBarButtonItem *yourButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" style: UIBarButtonStylePlain target:self action:@selector(myTargetMethodSignature:)];
navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourButton;
[yourButton release];
```

Hope this helps.
Wasabi

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial: [How do iPhone apps Instagram/Reeder/DailyBooth implement custom NavigationBars with variable width back buttons?](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/12/how-do-iphone-apps-instagramreederdailybooth-implement-custom-navigationbar-with-variable-width-back-buttons/). It includes a source code example.